# Проблемы переноса программ между платформами

Tags: windows, c#

Программа, написанная в Visual Studio (на C#) на Windows 7, не идет на XP. В чем проблема?

Comment: Приведите сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете через pinvoke специфические функции системы, приложение может не работать при переносе.

Comment: А конкретнее, что это значит?

Comment: Если приложение выходит за границы управляемого кода (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd315414.aspx) и обращается к компонентам системы (COM объектам или библиотекам, вроде User32.dll), то оно может быть непереносимым, потому что эти компоненты могут отличаться от версии к версии.

Answer (score 1):

Для борьбы с подобными проблемами полезным бывает логгирование исключений верхнего уровня. Для этого нужно подписаться на событие AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException и в обработчике записать в лог возникшее исключение.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве догадки: возможно, на Windows XP не установлен .NET Framework той версии, под которую собрано приложение.

Comment: NET Framework есть. В отдельных случаях даже запускается программа, но во время выполнения(при выполнении какого-либо действия)выдает ошибку.

Comment: Важно не только, чтобы он был, но и версии совпадали. На Windows 7 по умолчанию ставится 3.5 SP1. Если приложение именно под эту версию, а на Windows XP - версия ниже, то работать не будет.

Comment: При создании пакета установки ставил используемые фреймворки. Бесполезно. И что интересно, программы, созданные до переустановки системы работают.